# Svelte spa router, landing page not having the hash (#) after localhost:5000

Tags: routes, svelte

I am using svelte-spa-router which is a hash-based routing in svelte. In-app.svelte I am defining the routes like below:

```
<script>
 import Router from 'svelte-spa-router'  
 const routes = {
  '/': Login,
  '/home':Home,
  "/openlist/:id":CompList,
  "/orderOverview":ListOverview,
  "/addcompany":AddCompany
 }
</script>

<Router {routes}  />
  <HeaderTest />
  <svelte:component this={page1} {params} />
```

On the other svelte pages ex: Header.

By using the `use:link` in a link, it puts a `#(hash)` in the URL like this `http://10.11.65.60:5000/#/home` which is perfectly fine and what I want to achieve.

```
 <a href="/home" use:link >Home</a>
```

But when I run the app the landing page in this case login only goes to `http://10.11.65.60:5000/` not on `http://10.11.65.60:5000/#/` how I want it to be.

How can I put a hash also on the login page without having to press on a `<a>` but it automatically puts the hash when I open localhost.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to gain from this?

Comment: I am retrieving a token from another backend which is a SSO login and when I press a certain button on my login screen the url goes like  http://10.11.65.60:5000/?token=12345678 and when it navigates to home page it goes http://10.11.65.60:5000/?token=12345678#/home

Comment: That is a completely different issue from what you were asking and should have been part of the question. The token should ideally be consumed by the server followed by a redirect (which removes the token). You can also move or remove the token on the client, if necessary, though.

Comment: In general, a question should explain what you want to achieve at a high level, while providing the necessary implementation details. If you just explain some symptoms and ask for a fix, you will get a worse solution that does not address the root of the problem. Also, in this case it would be helpful to know what kind of server is being used, in particular, whether all sites are static or whether there are route handlers that could do something like consume the token and return a redirect.

Comment: Yes I dot the redirect (push in this case with svelte-spa-router) but still it puts the path like this " /?token=13213213#/home" after the token and it does that for each link on the website. Yes a certain server consumes the token and then I get an api of which I have to input a return link in this case localhost:5000.

Comment: By consuming the token I mean your application that needs to know (and possibly store) the token to use it. You still have not answered what your server is/does. A redirect via the SPA router is fully client-side and happens *after* the server has served the page.